# Reactor - How to use filterWhen and still pass the value for logging purposes if it doesn't pass the filter?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, reactor

I am trying to figure out the right way to do the following.

- I want to check if a record exists in database by `name`, which is a global secondary index. (Let's say the primary key is `id`).
- If there's already an item that has `name`, then log the `id` and `name` and returns an error.
- If there's not an item with the given `name`, then proceed.

Right now, the code structure looks like this.

```
private fun checkExistingData(name: String): Mono<QueryResponse> {
  return repo.getDataByName(name)
    .filterWhen { Mono.just(!it.hasItems()) }
    .switchIfEmpty {
      // log the existing id and name from QueryResponse
      Mono.error(SomeCustomException))
    }
    .flatMap {
      // proceed
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I want to log the `id` in the `switchIfEmpty` clause, I would need to do `repo.getDataByName(name)` in it to be able to retrieve the item and get the `id` of the item. Obviously, this is inefficient as I already do that prior to `switchIfEmpty`.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why not store the result of `repo.getDataByName()` in a variable and then access it inside `switchIfEmpty`?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: I don't know much about reactor, so can't answer properly, I'm just suggesting that instead of returning from the first line, you'd store the first line of your code as a variable and then return `variable.switchIfEmpty....` rest of code and inside switchIfEmpty you can access that particular `variable`, aren't you?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the `QueryResponse` object is always emitted, but you can determine wether or not there is an entry by doing `hasItems()`? And `hasItems()` returns a `Mono<Boolean>`? How do you access the items exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending more information on the `QueryResponse` API, I'm going to assume a few things:
 - `getDataByName` returns a `Mono<QueryResponse>`. This `Mono` is ALWAYS valued, ie it always emits exactly one `QueryResponse` wheter or not data could be found
 - `QueryResponse#items` is what I'll use in my example to access the rows proper. I'm going to also assume it returns a `Flux<Item>`

First off, `filterWhen` is not useful here since we also have a `filter(boolean)` method. I think that reversed filter logic is maybe a bit harder to follow.

Why not do everything in the `flatMap` instead?

```
private fun checkExistingData(name: String): Mono<QueryResponse> {
  return repo.getDataByName(name)
    .flatMap {
       if (it.hasItems())
         it.items()
           .single()
           .doOnNext(existing -> logExisting(existing.id(), existing.name())
           .then(Mono.error(SomeCustomException)
        else
          proceed()
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your first call to `repo.getDataByName` returns a `Mono` and this `Mono` is empty, then you don't need to filter for that case since the rest of the pipeline will not be called. So I think you can keep the `switchIfEmpty()` to log this particular case and then just continue you pipeline with `flatMap()`:

```
private fun checkExistingData(name: String): Mono<QueryResponse> {
  return repo.getDataByName(name)
    .switchIfEmpty {
      // log the existing id and name from QueryResponse
      Mono.error(SomeCustomException))
    }
    .flatMap {
      // proceed
    }
}
```